# Difference between 'find -delete' and 'rm -rf'?

Tags: unix, delete-file, rm

I want to delete files from a specific directory recursively. So, I have used

```
find . -wholename "*.txt" -delete
```

We can also delete the files using

```
rm -rf *.txt
```

What is the difference between deletion of file using `rm` and `find` ??

Comment: With `find` you get to be more specific about which files you remove, but both end up calling `unlink()` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) on the files you're deleting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`find . -name abd.txt -delete` tries to remove all files named `abd.txt` that are somewhere in the directory tree of `.`

`find . -wholename abd.txt -delete` tries to remove all files with a full pathname of `abd.txt` somewhere in the directory tree of `.`

No such files will ever exist: when using `find .`, all full pathnames of files found will start with `./`, so even a file in the current directory named `abd.txt` will have path `./abd.txt`, and it will not match.

`find . -wholename ./abd.txt -delete` *will* remove the file in the current directory named `abd.txt`.

`find -wholename ./abd.txt -delete` will do the same.

The removal will fail if `abd.txt` is a nonempty directory.

(I just tried the above with GNU find 4.6.0; other versions may behave differently.)

`rm -rf abd.txt` also tries to remove `abd.txt` in the current directory, and if it is a nonempty directory, it will remove it, and everything in it.

To do this with `find`, you might use

`find . -depth \( -wholename ./abd.txt -o -wholename ./abd.txt/\* \) -delete`

Comment: Okay. Then what is the difference between deletion using 'find -delete' and 'rm -rf' ?

Comment: Using `find ...` you scan also subdirectories, while using `rm` you scan only the files that are in the *current* directory, not in a subdirectory.

Comment: @MisterJack: with `-r`, `rm` also removes subdirectories.

Comment: @reinierpost my comment was for @Aashish P. And by the way `-r` is used to remove recursively the content of a file if that file is a directory, not to scan *also* subdirectories.

Comment: @MisterJack: technically, the contents of a file are not actually within the directory that the file is in (the directory just contains a filename and a pointer to the file), so what actually happens is a scan to remove everything, similar to `find . -depth -exec rm \{} +`

Comment: I just rewrote and extended this answer; the previous version was ignoring the difference between `-name` and `-wholename` :-(

Answer (score 3):

While `find -wholename GLOBPATTERN` tries to match every file below the current directory (independent of the depth), the glob you used with the `rm` command is only matched against files which are **directly** (depth 1) under the current directory.

Btw. you don't need the `-r` switch to `rm` unless you want to recursively delete a directory (Because of the `.txt` extension, I assume you only want to delete regular files)

Answer (score 2):

`find` used with `-delete`, finds the files and deletes them. `Find` command takes in the path to look for the files and then the `-delete` flag deletes the files found in that given path. So, you can say find is more of a **selective delete**

Whereas `rm -rf` command deletes files/directories recursively no matter what. It means `rm` will delete **all** the files and directories at the specific path. `-r` stands for recursion and `-f` is force delete. So, `rm` coupled with `-rf` will keep on deleting the directories and files within directories at the target path until it finds no more.